# How change values from Server System Variables

Tags: mysql

Here (https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/server-system-variables.html) is sad, it is possible change value by comand line.

And here (https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_ft_min_word_len) is your format, but where and how i un this command, is in shell mysql or prompt linux?

i try:

```
me:/$ sudo mysql --ft-min-word-len=2
```

and the same in mysql shell:

```
MySQL [(none)]> mysql --ft-min-word-len=2
```

But both display errors, what is my mistake?

Im new on dbmanegement.

Comment: They are *server* system variables, not *client*. They can be given on the command line for the *server* process. Or you can use the `SET` command in SQL like the document says.

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen tks for atention, u can say me one example to use SET to set ft-min-word-len=2? Im not sure but that variable is not dynamic, for use SET, a realy dont know...

Comment: That one most likely can’t be set other than on startup so it has to be in settings file or server startup command line unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

Try one of these :

1-In query editor, run `set global ft-min-word-len=2;`

2-Or in command line, use `mysqld --ft-min-word-len=2` not `mysql`

3-Edit your config file (eg: `/etc/mysql/my.cnf`) , insert after `[mysqld]` section

```
[mysqld] 
ft-min-word-len = 2
```

Comment: for 1- i think is wrong, that work only with dynamic variables, for 2 and 3 i think i right, and in my case (i know i dont put im my question) neither that options  work, becouse im use GCP and need set variablies direct in Cloud SQL... If u right this datails i can mark your answer, tks for atention.